# Adding ID's in a jade template inside a P HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I created this paragraph using the jade template which works. I wanted put an ID or class around the word stackoverflow, how could I do that in jade? I know when using normal HTML we could use something like `<div class="className">'stackoverflow'</div>` or use `span`, I tried to look at the jade documentation but couldn't find anything.

```
  p.we_are
  | We are 
  | in love with 'stackoverflow' so much
  | because it rules.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as you expect.

```
p.we_are
   | We are 
   | in love with '
   p#id stackoverflow
   |' so much
   | because it rules.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline tags:

```
p.we_are
  | We are 
  | in love with #[div#idName 'stackoverflow'] so much
  | because it #[div.className rules].
```